# Battery with inner resistance circuit problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

"Battery Ba is connected in series with resistor Ra = 2Ω. Battery Bb is connected in series with resistor Rb = 4Ω.
Battery Ba has a voltage of 2V and inner resistance of 1Ω. Bb has a voltage of 1V and inner resistance of 2Ω. The two circuits are connected in parallell in a way that the polarity on Bb is switched (+ on Ba is connected to - on Bb). What is the current flowing through Bb and voltage drop of Rb?"

First of all I have a bit of trouble to sketch the circuit. This is my attempt (not sure if it's correct)
[image]

If it's correct. My attempt was to do node analysis on the upper (three-way node). But I'm not sure on how to take into account the inner resistance of the batteries when calculating.

Could this be the correct interpretation of the problem?
[image]

Comment: We need you to be accurate in your diagram.

Comment: I wasnt sure on how to draw the battery using a schematic tool

Comment: Use EveryCircuit or similar software (this one has an online version), sketch it there and you'll see "the electrons" flowing, the voltage, amperage and everything you need and don't need to know.

Comment: Did my best, hopefully that circuit is better to understand

Comment: I don't think you want the wire from the top horizontal line, around the circuit to Ground.

Comment: This line which is connecting the top of the circuit to the bottom is effectively making two different circuits (one that is containing the left part and one for the right part). So you can redraw them and solve separately.

Comment: Could it be that I have misunderstood the problem? Because the circuits should be one and not two separately.

Comment: Ah, I see, the schematic is not given, it is your interpretation of the wording. Then I guess it is not correct. But the wording is vague as well. "Battery Bb is connected to resistor Rb with 4Ω" - connected how? "The two circuits are connected in parallell" - if these are circuits, it implies that there should be some closed path in each one. You need to get clarification on it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the description of your circuit which would lead to that wire short-circuiting the top and bottom.

Comment: @brhans What is your interpretation of the circuit? I dont see how I should get the two batteries parallell when they are not connected in that way.

Comment: Your description does not ask for the 2 *batteries* to be connected in parallel., it asks for the 2 *circuits* to be connected in parallel. So the series circuit consisting of Ra + Ba is to be connected in parallel with the other series circuit consisting of Rb + Bb. That extra wire is not needed to accomplish this.

Comment: @brhans Am I correct now with the lower image?

Comment: yes, I believe that's what the question text intends - it makes much more sense that way.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I finally have a chance at solving it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do it step-by step:

1. Battery Ba is connected in series with resistor Ra = 2Ω.
2. Battery Bb is connected in series with resistor Rb = 4Ω.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foGzlw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

3. Battery Ba has a voltage of 2V and inner resistance of 1Ω.
4. Bb has a voltage of 1V and inner resistance of 2Ω.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Ozgo.png)</sup>

5. The two circuits are connected in parallell in a way that the polarity on Bb is switched (+ on Ba is connected to - on Bb).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVYRoE.png)</sup>

The location of the 0V reference node is arbitrary. I've put it inside the schematic just so I wouldn't need to enlarge the box the schematic is in :)

> What is the current flowing through Bb and voltage drop of Rb?

Hint: how would you connect two AA batteries to obtain 3V?

You can do DC simulation on the schematic above and check your answers and intuition, by the way!